# react-router error pathname.match is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm getting

> pathname.match is not a function

error when I use [matchPath](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath) of `react-router`.

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
import { matchPath, useLocation } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const MatcherControl = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const match = matchPath(location.pathname, {
    path: "/users/:id",
    exact: true,
    strict: false
  });
  return <div>{match ? "matches" : "not matches"}</div>;
};
```

This is the minimal example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/match-path-router-o5g2s) to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `react-router` v6 that the order of `matchPath` arguments is inverted in new version:

```
declare function matchPath<
  ParamKey extends string = string
>(
  pattern: PathPattern | string,
  pathname: string
): PathMatch<ParamKey> | null;

interface PathMatch<ParamKey extends string = string> {
  params: Params<ParamKey>;
  pathname: string;
  pattern: PathPattern;
}

interface PathPattern {
  path: string;
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  end?: boolean;
}
```

Check it [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.6.1/utils/match-path)

You should pass the `pattern` first , and then `pathname` :

```
const match = matchPath(
  { path: "/users/:id" },
  location.pathname,
);
```

Comment: nothing better than a breaking API change that changes nothing